# multi radio buttons not shown in Android - strange behavior

Tags: android, radio-button

For me very strange error.
I did something similar with TextView and everything works like a charm, so I assume that it should work also for Radio Button

I have a problem with radio button in android. When I set a value on a one button everything is ok. But when I rotate device, something strange begins to happening.

OR the values are not shown, OR are all the same value, OR it is impossible to click on value that has been previously set(and it's invisible)

I did check the saved values, and they are ok.
Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you very much.

code:

```
package com.example.radiobutton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;

/**
 * 
 */

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<ItemL> mItemList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mItemList =  HolderItemL.get(getActivity()).getList() ;

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, parent, false);
    LinearLayout topLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.top_layout);

    showPanel(topLayout, inflater, parent);

    return v;
}



private void showPanel(LinearLayout topLayout, LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
    for(int i = 0; i < mItemList.size(); i++){
        final ItemL product = (ItemL) mItemList.get(i);
        View aLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_layout,  parent, false);
        ((ViewGroup) topLayout).addView(aLayout);

        View rrrt = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_radio_layout,  parent, false);
        ((ViewGroup) aLayout).addView(rrrt);    

        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) rrrt.findViewById(R.id.aditivs_radio_group);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch(checkedId) {
                case R.id.radio_alergen_yes_contian:
                    product.setContain(true);
                    break;
                case R.id.radio_alergen_not_contain:
                    product.setContain(false);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }); 


        RadioButton yesContain = (RadioButton) rrrt.findViewById(R.id.radio_alergen_yes_contian);
        RadioButton notContain = (RadioButton) rrrt.findViewById(R.id.radio_alergen_not_contain);
        if(product.isContain() != null){
            if(product.isContain().booleanValue()){
                yesContain.setChecked(true);
                System.out.println("#contain yes#");
            }
            else{
                notContain.setChecked(true);
                System.out.println("#contain not#");
            }
        }
    }
}
}



class HolderItemL {

public static ArrayList<ItemL> listItems = new ArrayList<ItemL>();
private static HolderItemL sHolderItemL;
private Context mAppContext;

private HolderItemL(Context context){
    mAppContext = context;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        ItemL l = new ItemL();
        listItems.add(l);
    }
}

public static HolderItemL get(Context c) {
    if(sHolderItemL == null){
        sHolderItemL = new HolderItemL(c.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sHolderItemL;
}

public ArrayList<ItemL> getList(){
    return listItems;
}
}



class ItemL {

private Boolean contain;

public Boolean isContain() {
    return contain;
}

public void setContain(boolean contain) {
    this.contain = contain;
}
 }
```

xml:Activiti_main

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

xml:Fragment_main

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

xml:group_radio_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/aditivs_radio_group"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_alergen_yes_contian"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yes_contian" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_alergen_not_contain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="not_contain" />
    </RadioGroup>


</LinearLayout>
```

xml: radio_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/alergen_name_title"
    style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve the problem, by removing the xml files for radio buttons and I showed them dynamically.
Now all the logic is working ok.

Well it's true that I still don't know what cause the error with xml. So any explanation is appreciated.